# Problems with ReadRawVarint32() - Google Protocol Buffers csharp-port

Tags: c#, java, protocols, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to receive some data from a client in a server using Google Protocol Buffers, concretely, Jon Skeet's csharp-port. I do the following:

```
using Google.ProtocolBuffers;
...
Stream InputStream = client.GetStream();
CodedInputStream input = CodedInputStream.CreateInstance(InputStream);
...
uint length = CodedInputStream.ReadRawVarint32(InputStream);
```

I get an error message from the last line which i cannot solve: An object reference is requiered to access non-static member '*Google.ProtocolBuffers.CodedInputStream.ReadRawVarint32()*'.

Basicly what i want to do would be like this in the java version:

```
InputStream iStream = client.getInputStream();
CodedInputStream input = CodedInputStream.newInstance(iStream);
int read = is.read();
if(-1 != read) {
    int length = CodedInputStream.readrawVarint32(read, is);
    byte[] bytes = input.readRawBytes(length);
    // My proto stuff
    Communication.Packet container = null;
    try {
        container = Communication.Packet.parseFrom(bytes);
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException iPBE) {
        continue;
    }
    AbstractMessage message = container;
    if(container.hasLogin()) {
        message = container.getLogin();
    }
    System.out.println(message.toString());
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states that you are trying to access a non-static (i.e. a member method) without using an object reference. You need to change your method call to operate on the object of type CodedInputStream instead of the CodedInputStream class:

`input.ReadRawVarint32();`